# Predicate and distinct objects

Tags: objective-c, core-data, predicate, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have entity `Unit` and `Tag`, each with to-many relation to other.

I am using `NSFetchedResultsController` to manage the data. What I need is to return distinct `Unit` object into `NSFetchedResultsController` for condition `Tag.show == YES`. I'm not sure how to feed all this to `NSFetchedResultsController`. Set entity to `Unit` or `Tag`, how to build predicate for it.

Example:

I have 6 `Tag` objects `tag1...tag6` and 3 Unit object `unit1, unit2, unit3`. 
tag1, tag2 are pointing to unit1, tag3, tag4 to unit2. 
tag1...tag4 met `show == YES` condition.
So I want finally to get uni1 and unit2 into `NSFetchedResultsController`.

Comment: Is this Visual Basic or Delphi?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a fetch on the `Unit` entity with a predicate of `"ANY Tag.show==YES"`.

That will return any `Unit` instances that has one or more related `Tag` instances with `show==YES`. Fetches return distinct objects so you don't have to do anything else.

Comment: I just discovered same and good to see your post! You are always helpful, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I tried this on one of my problems.

If have a NSMutableArray filled with RSSItem objects, which - amongst others - contain a property link, which is a NSString.

Now I want to find all objects in the array, which's link is equal to another NSString `[item link]`.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = 
      [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY link == '%@'", [item link]];
NSArray *filteredArray = 
      [[delegate itemArray] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
if ([filteredArray count] > 0) {
      // IF such an object exists, do something ...
}
```

Isn't that the same thing, you were trying?
Or am I misunderstanding something about predicates here?

Greetings,
Dodo

Comment: Found the mistake. You do not need the additional '  ' around that string. Sometimes it's that easy ... even though it took me about three hours to figure that out. :(